# How to update the table value using ajax with foreach jstl in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

```
**This is ajax function**

  $.ajax({  
     type : "Get",   
     url : url, 
     data:$("#client").serialize(),
     dataType:'json',
     success : function(response) 
     {  

     },  
     error : function(e) 
     {  
      alert('Error: ' + e); 

     }  
    });
```

This is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate/ajaxObj", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<String> ajax_Claims(Model model, 
    @ModelAttribute("CalculatorDO") CalculatorDO calculatorDO)  
    {
        System.out.println("\nAjax Hit the Controller");
        ArrayList<String> clist=new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> namelist=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> classlist=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> address=new ArrayList<>();
        namelist=calculatorDO.getNameList();
        classlist=calculatorDO.getNameList();
        address=calculatorDO.getNameList();

        clist.add(namelist);
        clist.add(classlist);
        clist.add(address);

        model.addAttribute("nameList", clist);
        return clist;
    }
```

My table

```
<table>    
    <thead>        
    <tr>                                                      
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>address</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${nameList}" var="list">    
       <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${list.namelist}"/></td>      
        <td><c:out value="${list.classlist}" /></td>  
        <td><c:out value="${list.address}"/></td>              
      </tr> 
    </c:forEach> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to reload the table.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<tbody>` with

```
<tbody id="ajax-tbody-results">
                </tbody>
```

And use jQuery tmpl to fill the table with your data ([jQuery tmpl](https://github.com/KanbanSolutions/jquery-tmpl) )

```
<script id="table-template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
          <tr>  
            <td>${namelist}</td>
            <td>${classlist}</td>

           </tr>
    </script>

      $.ajax({  
             type : "Get",   
             url : url, 
             dataType:'json',
             success : function(response) 
             {  
                 jQuery("#table-template").tmpl(data).appendTo("#ajax-tbody-results");
             },  
             error : function(e) 
             {  
              alert('Error: ' + e); 

             }  
        });
```